# Indentation in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, richtextbox, core-text, nsattributedstring

I have a piece of text like this:

```
Hello World  Hello World  Hello World Hello World  Hello World  Hello World Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World-  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World Hello World  Hello World  Hello World Hello World  Hello World  Hello World -  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World
```

Is it possible using `NSAttributedString` to get something like this:

```
 Hello World  Hello World  Hello World Hello World  Hello World  Hello World
 Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World
 -  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World Hello World  Hello World  Hello World
    Hello World  Hello World  Hello World
 -  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World 
    Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World
```

For me the problem is getting the indentation on the second line after the "-". At the moment I am able to achieve this:

```
 Hello World  Hello World  Hello World Hello World  Hello World  Hello World
 Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World
 -  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World Hello World  Hello World  Hello World
 Hello World  Hello World  Hello World
 -  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World 
 Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World  Hello World
```

In the example I am using 2 lines for each "-" but could be more, or just one.

I though of using an `UIWebView` or separate the text into different `UITextViews`, but I find it a bit clumsy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afte searching for innumerous 3rd party libraries, I settled with an `UIWebView`. I don't think I could achieve a better looking text with some other stuff. Some of the ones I tried:

- [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText)
- [RTLabel](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel)
- [TTTAttributeLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel)
- [Core-Text-Label](https://github.com/newsme/Core-Text-Label)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CoreText Framework in order to enhance the functionality of TextView as well as playing freely with the Text. Hope it Helps.